# Update all rows to same value or update certain ones only?

Tags: sql, optimization, sql-update

There's a table with one column "scores" and 10 rows in it. 2 rows have 10 scores, the other 8 have 0 scores. I want to set all rows' scores to 0. Which way is more optimized?:

1. `UPDATE <table> SET scores = 0`
2. `UPDATE <table> SET scores = 0 WHERE scores <> 0`

Comment: I would think option two, it takes less restrictive locks than what would be required for option one as well as it would only update rows that actually need it. Keep in mind, your system, schema and data all play factors in this though.

Comment: I would always favour the second option. Let the DBMS update exactly the rows that need an update. Every row you update may result in a lock, additional checks, an entry in a rollback area, an audit log entry, and in firing triggers that themselves could perform costly operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on the database you are using.

Some databases check to see if a value is changing before updating a row (and incurring the overhead of logging).

Some databases update all specified rows, even if the value doesn't change.

In general, though, I would use the `WHERE` clause.  However, you do need to be careful about `NULL` values in that case.

And, for 12 rows, performance doesn't really matter.